# How to install MS fonts on Ubuntu?

Tags: fonts, software-installation

I did `sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer` and it seems it is successfully.
But why I am not seeing new fonts? (e.g. when I got to select font in my profile for my terminal)?

```bash
$ sudo apt-get install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
[sudo] password for cheungs: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ttf-mscorefonts-installer
0 upgraded, 1 newly installed, 0 to remove and 387 not upgraded.
Need to get 0 B/27.4 kB of archives.
After this operation, 133 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Preconfiguring packages ...
Selecting previously unselected package ttf-mscorefonts-installer.
(Reading database ... 198874 files and directories currently installed.)
Unpacking ttf-mscorefonts-installer (from .../ttf-mscorefonts-installer_3.4ubuntu3_all.deb) ...
mscorefonts-eula license has already been accepted
Processing triggers for fontconfig ...
Processing triggers for update-notifier-common ...
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/andale32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arial32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/arialb32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/comic32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/courie32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/georgi32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/impact32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/times32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/trebuc32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/verdan32.exe
ttf-mscorefonts-installer: downloading http://downloads.sourceforge.net/corefonts/webdin32.exe

These fonts were provided by Microsoft "in the interest of cross-
platform compatibility".  This is no longer the case, but they are
still available from third parties.

You are free to download these fonts and use them for your own use,
but you may not redistribute them in modified form, including changes
to the file name or packaging format.

Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpKiZJn9.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting andale.inf
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting AndaleMo.TTF
  extracting ADVPACK.DLL
  extracting W95INF32.DLL
  extracting W95INF16.DLL

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpscRkMp.exe
  extracting FONTINST.EXE
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Ariali.TTF
  extracting Arialbd.TTF
  extracting Arialbi.TTF
  extracting Arial.TTF

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpbj6o_K.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting AriBlk.TTF

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpPcR86z.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Comicbd.TTF
  extracting Comic.TTF
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpOhqPyy.exe
  extracting cour.ttf
  extracting courbd.ttf
  extracting courbi.ttf
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting couri.ttf
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmp4d_sD6.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Georgiaz.TTF
  extracting Georgiab.TTF
  extracting Georgiai.TTF
  extracting Georgia.TTF
  extracting fontinst.exe

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpWCFmAL.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Impact.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpdBzrJ6.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Times.TTF
  extracting Timesbd.TTF
  extracting Timesbi.TTF
  extracting Timesi.TTF
  extracting FONTINST.EXE

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpu_gD4C.exe
  extracting FONTINST.EXE
  extracting trebuc.ttf
  extracting Trebucbd.ttf
  extracting trebucbi.ttf
  extracting trebucit.ttf
  extracting fontinst.inf

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmpLiBv4G.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Verdanab.TTF
  extracting Verdanai.TTF
  extracting Verdanaz.TTF
  extracting Verdana.TTF

All done, no errors.
Extracting cabinet: /tmp/tmp_4WDyE.exe
  extracting fontinst.exe
  extracting Webdings.TTF
  extracting fontinst.inf
  extracting Licen.TXT

All done, no errors.
All fonts downloaded and installed.
Setting up ttf-mscorefonts-installer (3.4ubuntu3) ...
```

Comment: In libreoffice, can you see these fonts? I think Terminal application doesn't support microsoft ttf fonts.Because, i also can't see these fonts when I got to select font in my profile for my terminal.

Comment: the fonts are also available unpacked on the web: [google search for the fonts](https://www.google.de/search?q=georgiab.ttf%20intitle:index.of%20site:.edu)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The fonts were definitely correctly installed, says the log.

Your problem, however, probably lies less with the fact that the fonts aren't in the list, but with the fact that you're trying to use the wrong fonts. The GUI terminal profile manager only allows choosing **fixed width** or **monospace** fonts by default. That means, a font with which you can see (if you definitely want it on the Terminal) whether or not the `msfonts` are accessible from within Ubuntu would be the `Courier New`.

They should also be available in LibreOffice, however.

There may be a way to force a non-monospace font to be displayed in the Terminal through altering the profile files to point to the correct font, but that's discouraged as monospace fonts are intended to make text-only formatting (f.e. ASCII drawings, character-based tables) possible.

Comment: You might need to log out and back in again to see the new fonts in LibreOffice if you just installed them... The new fonts are not available right away in the current session. Just sayin'...

Answer (score 0):

In LibreOffice Writer, access Tools -> Options -> Fonts
Put a check in the Apply replacement table field. Replace some font you don't 
want with the one you do.  Writer seems to make all new fonts available at
that time.