# Format problem docx File in Libre Writer?

Tags: libreoffice

I've asked this thread before:

[Problem with Libre Office in Ubuntu 13.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/402210/problem-with-libre-office-in-ubuntu-13-04/402221?noredirect=1#402221)

Now the problem is just the reverse. Openning a docx file in Libre Office Writer shows a kind of format problem like font, size of font increases, images overlapping eachother.

Any way to solve it.Please help !

Comment: For the mean time Libre Office only support the conversion of the text and images in docx document, and everything is defaulted to Libre Office standard. It can be also some missing fonts from Windows fonts (the font Calibri is not available in Ubuntu). Libre Office does not support the size and position yet.

Comment: Have you installed **Microsoft fonts** in the Ubuntu machine with LibreOffice? http://askubuntu.com/questions/216819/how-to-install-ms-fonts-on-ubuntu-12-04 may help. MSFonts are not installed by default in Ubuntu. docx files use MSFonts. LibreOffice substitutes the installed fonts as best as it can. Installing the MSFonts will allow LibreOffice to use those fonts when you open docx files ctreated in MSWord.

Comment: Calibri and Cambria are not part of the Ubuntu Microsoft fonts package, so you would have to [copy them from MS Windows or find some compatible alterantive fonts](http://ask.libreoffice.org/en/question/15041/calibri-and-cambria-fonts-in-libreoffice/)

Answer (score 2):

If the `.docx` file is produced with LibreOffice than there should not be any problem, since LibreOffice uses a strict ISO-compatible format.

On the other side, if it is produced by Microsoft Office, then it is very difficult that you find a way to show it correctly in LibreOffice (apart for the fonts that may be missing or that are different on your Ubuntu system), since Microsoft uses a non-strict transitional proprietary ISO format that no one else can use.

[Source](http://brattahlid.wordpress.com/2012/05/08/is-docx-really-an-open-standard/)

Answer (score 2):

> Any way to solve it.Please help !

If possible use `.doc` or save the `.docx` file as a `.doc`. It is almost fully supported and will have less problems when opening the file in LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

Try using SoftMaker FreeOffice instead of LibreOffice.

You get it at freeoffice.com, it's a full-fledged, free office suite.

FreeOffice has very good import and export filters for Microsoft Office formats, and you should be able to open your docx without formatting losses. No other free office suite gives such excellent interoperability with MS Office in both directions.

Please note that opening docx works perfect, but saving is only possible as doc; if you need to save in docx, you require the pay-for version SoftMaker Office (which has also more features and templates, free technical support and an included macro language).

More info at http://www.freeoffice.com/

Answer (score 0):

Actually, Microsoft Office 2013 has had read/write capability for ISO/IEC 29500 (Strict Open XML) [since 2012-08-13](http://blogs.office.com/2012/08/13/new-file-format-options-in-the-new-office/).

Theoretically, any .docx file exported in that format should be editable in LibreOffice, yet my personal experience is that it does not work. I don't know whether to believe that Microsoft didn't implement 29500 properly or LibreOffice.

Answer (score 0):

What about vmware or virtualbox or playonlinux? The easiest way may be to install Microsoft Office via playonlinux. No trials with different office suits or setting required. it will be formatted as just like the way created.

Answer (score 0):

As for alternative software, if you decide to try that, check Kingsoft Office. More at the [following answer to "Can Kingsoft Office be installed?"](https://askubuntu.com/a/310204/58950).